# Date to Chart but only when present

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am making a leave planner for staff once i put start date and end date it calculate number of days formula is (=c2-B2) and number of days shows in a chart
Problem is when staff apply for one day leave with this formula it shows 0 day but in real he took leave for one day
[image]
[image]

If i use this formula it shows 1 =IF(DATEDIF(b2,c2,"D")=0,1,DATEDIF(b2,c2,"D"))

but if date cells are empty it still shows 1 which reflects wrong in chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
=IF(OR(B2=0,C2=0),"",IF(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")=0,1,DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")))
```

I included one additional condition (if one of the dates is 0, it shows 0).

Comment: If result cell value is zero after c2-b2 i want to show 1 but if c2 and b2  is empty then D2 should be empty also not showing anything eg C2= Endate B2 = Start date D2  = end date - startdate

Comment: @pnuts yes sir pasted it in formula bar and tick it

Comment: @KzhelFarmer if you want to show nothing when it's empty, use this updated formula: `=IF(OR(B2=0,C2=0),"",IF(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")=0,1,DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")))`

Comment: @pnuts after paste in formula bar i enter

Comment: @SergeyRyabov Yes the edited version works as i want Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(B2+C2=0,0,IF(DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")=0,1,DATEDIF(B2,C2,"D")))
```

This just traps when B2 and C2 are both empty and returns `0` - prempting the remainder of your formula.